# Graceful error handling and logging in Jinja extension

Tags: python, exception, logging, error-handling, jinja2

I'm developing a Jinja extension that performs a few potentially harmful operations, which on failure will raise an Exception that holds some information on what went wrong.

When this occurs, of course the Exception will prevent Jinja from completing its render process and return `None` rather than a render result. This problem is easily mitigated using a try/catch statement and returning an empty string or whatever is suitable.

However, that effectively throws away the Exception and the debugging info, which I would rather pass on to my error log. The system responsible for setting up the Jinja environment has it's own logging service, which I would prefer to keep decoupled from the extension. I am aware though, that Jinja has an [`Undefined` class](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#undefined-types) which I have successfully used to intercept access of undefined variables in another project.

Is there any way I could raise a special type of exception (`UndefinedException` did not work), or tell the Jinja environment to log a warning, when an error occurs in my extension, while still allowing it to continue its execution?

What I have in mind is something along the lines of this example:

```
def _render(*args, **kwrags):
    # ...
    try:
        self.potentially_harmful_operation()
    except Exception as e:
        self.environment.warning(e)
        return Markup("")
    # ...
    return Markup('<img src"{}">'.format(img_path))
```

So, to clarify, as I wrote in a comment below:

> Fundamentally I guess my question boils down to "how can I make Jinja produce a warning, as it does for e.g. missing variables".

Comment: Why not use the standard python `logging`?

Comment: I could do that of course, but this system has logging set up already. This custom logging service is essentially an abstraction layer that could forward to `logging`, `syslogd` or something else. Since Jinja is capable of emitting warnings I figured it'd be neat to use that and just forward the warnings. Fundamentally I guess my question boils down to "how can I make Jinja produce a warning, as it does for e.g. missing variables".

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that you wanted to avoid the custom logging layer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the problem correctly. But you could set `environment.undefined` to a custom class that won't throw exception when accessed or when operations are applied to. Also i'm not sure if using the generator for parsing the template can be usefull (and transform exception as warning when needed
).

Comment: Thanks @Cyrbil, that's more or less how I ended up solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to solve this by implementing my own `Undefined` class (largely inspired by [`make_logging_undefined`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/9b4b20aa56fde3a5cd5ac49d4feacd96eacb832d/jinja2/runtime.py#L531) and supplying that to the environment using the `undefined` keyword. Depending on your needs, the default `make_logging_undefined` might very well suffice.

Once that's in place, the trick is to emit the warning in the environment. This is done by simply instantiating the environment's `Undefined` and executing one of its magic methods (e.g. `__str__`). Hooking on to my example code from above, that could be accomplished like this:

```
def _render(*args, **kwrags):
    # ...
    try:
        self.potentially_harmful_operation()
    except Exception as e:
        str(self.environment.undefined(e))
        return Markup("")
    # ...
    return Markup('<img src"{}">'.format(img_path))
```